# Creating a link in VueJS to pass JSON value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a VueJS template file (let's call it *Template A*) that consists of a table which is populated by data from a JSON output.

**Sample JSON output:**

```
{"driver_id":1,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"13","driver_trailer":"83","driver_status":"driving","has_violations":false},
{"driver_id":2,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"58","driver_trailer":"37","driver_status":"sleeping","has_violations":true},
{"driver_id":3,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"80","driver_trailer":"27","driver_status":"driving","has_violations":true},
```

So the table looks like this:

[image: Sample table]

The button there is conditionally rendered whenever `has_violations` equals true. Here is the button code:

```
<template slot="list_of_violations" slot-scope="row">
<b-button v-if="row.value.list_of_violations == true" id="account_list">View Account LIst</b-button></template>
```

What I want to do is have this button become a link to another template vuejs file (let's called it *Template B*) in which will take the `driver_id` from Template A and then does the following:

1. Send AJAX request for all current to backend application violations
   for `driver_id` (from *Template A*)
2. Read Ajax response
3. Print Ajax results into table in *Template B*

My issue here is creating the link between the two templates and passing on the `driver_id` from *Template A* to *Template B*.

Is that state management? Nested routing? I am really confused here.

Comment: I think you need to redefine your question since it appears to be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#ad) (properties). In your case that could look like:

```html
<template-b driver-id="{{ driver_id }}"></template-b>
```

The `driver-id` prop can be used within Template **B**:

```js
// Modified example from the VueJS documentation
Vue.component('template-b', {
    // Accept the 'driver-id' property
    props: ['driverId'], // props are camelCase in JavaScript
    template: 'Print results for {{ driverId }}'
});
```

Inside template **B**, you could fetch the data from the server, using AJAX. This data can be stored and used within template B.

It's up to you how and where you want to show template **B**. For example: store the `driver_id` of the clicked row in the state of template **A**. Next: check if that `driver_id` has a value, and show template **B**:

```html
<template-b v-if="driver_id" driver-id="{{ driver_id }}"></template-b>
```

The `driver_id` comes from state of template **A**. Whenever you click on a button inside a different row, you simply update the `driver_id` in the state, and template **B** will update automatically. Note that you should create a [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the `driver_id` prop inside template **B**.

Comment: would i use then v-bind for the button generation to send the data to _Template B_?

Comment: @qeku You can use an 'on click' (`v-on:click` or `@click`) attribute, which executes a method. More info: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on